# archivemount (tar) returns before writing complete (sync on write?)

Tags: tar, archive

I just learned about `archivemount` some days ago, and it sounds like exactly the solution I need for a backup problem I have with `ecryptfs`. However, in my tests, it seems that archivemount exits before the (`sync`) write completes. In other words, I don't actually know when I can unmount the parent filesystem (ie, remove the drive that the .tar is in) because the command returns before it is actually "done" writing to disk (I can see disk thrashing in my local machine during tests, as well as monitor the available disk space decreasing). I see there are certain options that give me a hint as to how to solve this, but I am not sure if any are the actual solution.

```
   -o direct_io
          use direct I/O

   -o async_read
          perform reads asynchronously (default)

   -o sync_read
          perform reads synchronously
```

In section `MacFUSE mount options`:

```
   -o nosynconclose
          disable sync-on-close behavior (enabled by default)

   -o nosyncwrites
          disable synchronous-writes behavior (dangerous)
```

So, how can I detect once the data has *actually* finished being written to disk and it is safe to remove the drive (on the command line)?

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke `archivemounter`, it simply *mounts* your archive, it does not perform any write operations on it, that's why it does not block.

After mounting, *you* write files to the mountpoint, and you're supposed to `umount` the mountpoint before unmounting the parent filesystem. Unless there is a bug in `archivemounter`, that `umount` will block and sync until all data is written to the archive.

If you want `archivemounter` to always block write operations, `-o direct_io` is indeed what you want. If you're unsure, you can always invoke `sync -- /path/to/archive` yourself after `umount` (or before unmounting the parent filesystem)